# Java: Switch to new process creation style (from Runtime.getRuntime() to ProcessBuilder)

Tags: java, windows, process

```
String command = "cmd.exe /c \"dir -d\"";
File workingDir = new File("C:\\");

boolean newProcessStyle = true;
if (newProcessStyle) {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    //redirect std_err to std_out
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true)
            .directory(workingDir);
    p = pb.start();
} else {
    String[] env = {};
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, env, workingDir);
}
```

The old style works fine, the new does not: cmd.exe not found.
Do I need to set the PATH manually when I use processBuilder?

btw: I still wonder why the standard_ouput (stdout) of a process is obtained by p.getInputStream() and not by p.getOutputStream(). Why was it named after the return type, not after functionality?!

EDIT:
Additional question:
To make sure the subprocess is not blocking on full stdout buffer, one needs to read the output buffer:

```
InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    output += line + "\n";
}
p.waitFor();
```

What I don't understand: If reader.readLine() returns null, the buffer is empty. What if the subprocess writes to stdout after the parent process has exited the while loop? Isn't this causing the same potential deadlock problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `ProcessBuilder`, each part is given separately, executable and args.

You should use:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c",  "dir -d").start();
```

For the additional question:
`reader.readLine()` is blocking and waits until a line can be read (expecting a line separator). It returns null only when buffer has been completly read (ie it can be closed).
So, your while loop will not be finished until the end of the stream has been reached.

Comment: So what if I have more parameters? like a.exe /a b /c d /e f ?
I think there is not an infinite number of constructors for ProcessBuilder?!

Why is this notation used? It is quite inconvenient I think.

Comment: In your case, you can have just 2 parameters: executable and argurments (all arguments in one string parameter), but these 2 parameters are needed. But yes, you can also pass an infinite number of parameters, it is a varargs parameter in signature

Comment: varargs parameter ? I did not know that this exists. nice to know.
Can you also answer the additional question about the stdout?

Comment: I have just edited my answer to add the answer of your additional question

Comment: Thanks. I understand that It is looping until the buffer is empty. But what if the buffer is empfty, the while loop is exited and the child process fills the buffer again?
If it waits for an actual close of the stdout stream by the child process, then p.waitFor() is not necessary, as the stream will be closed when the process terminates - right?

Comment: No, it doesn't loop until the buffer is empty, it loop until the buffer has reach the end (like a EOF character), ie when the child process has closed the buffer and not when it prints currently nothing

Comment: So why use the p.waitfor then? Is my assumption wrong, that stdout is only closed on termination?!

Comment: `waitFor()` returns additionnal information, like the exit code. and useally, we don't need to read stdout buffer, and we don't need to do this in same thread. `waitFor()` let us check/wait/ensure anywhere the end of the execution.